# Ruby - converting a string into hash with each character as key and index as value?

Tags: ruby, hash

I am trying to transform a given string into a hash with each its character = key and index = value.

For example, if I have `str = "hello"`, I would like it to transform into `{"h"=>0, "e"=>1, "l"=>2, "l"=>3, "o"=>4}`.

I created a method as such:

```
def map_indices(arr)
  arr.map.with_index {|el, index| [el, index]}.to_h
end
#=> map_indices('hello'.split(''))
#=> {"h"=>0, "e"=>1, "l"=>3, "o"=>4}
```

The problem is it skips the first `l`. If I reverse the order of `el` and `index`:   `arr.map.with_index {|el, index| [index, el]}.to_h`, I get all the letters spelled out: `{0=>"h", 1=>"e", 2=>"l", 3=>"l", 4=>"o"}`

But when I `invert` it, I get the same hash that skips one of the `l`'s.

```
map_indices('hello'.split('')).invert
#=> {"h"=>0, "e"=>1, "l"=>3, "o"=>4}
```

Why is this behaving like such? How can I get it to print `{"h"=>0, "e"=>1, "l"=>2, "l"=>3, "o"=>4}`?

Comment: you can only have ONE unique key. So the double "l" will never work. Try the other way around. Index as key

Comment: A hash maps a key to a value. You have to decide what value you want the key `'l'` to map to. Question: what should your proposed hash return, when queried for the key `'l'`?

Comment: Please provide some background on why you need that. As have been said, it is not possible to have more than one value to the same key. Suppose you try to access `my_hash['l']`, what value should it return, 2 or 3?

Comment: If you don't have a hard requirement on having a hash, I provided another option as an answer.

Comment: This isn't a good idea. What is the need for a hash that behaves this way? There's a lot of smell going on.

Comment: @Rusian, that's not correct. `{a: 1, b: 2}`, for example, has two unique keys. :-). I think you mean is "all hash keys are unique".

Comment: As others have said, it doesn't make much sense this way. If you want it the other way around (index -> letter), you don't need to do anything : `"hello"[2] #=> 'l' `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of the following could be used. For

```
str = "hello"
```

all return

```
{"h"=>[0], "e"=>[1], "l"=>[2, 3], "o"=>[4]}
```

---

```
str.each_char
   .with_index
   .with_object({}) { |(c,i),h| (h[c] ||= []) << i }
```

See [String#each_char](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-each_char), [Enumerator#with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) and [Enumerator#with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object). The block variables have been written to exploit [array decomposition](https://jsarbada.wordpress.com/2019/02/05/destructuring-with-ruby/).

---

```
str.each_char
   .with_index
   .with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |(c,i),h| h[c] << i }
```

See the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a block and no argument. If a hash has been defined

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

and later

```
h[c] << i
```

is executed, `h[c]` is first set equal to an empty array if `h` does not have a key `c`.

---

```
str.size
   .times
   .with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |i,h| h[str[i]] << i }
```

---

```
str.each_char
   .with_index
   .group_by(&:first)
   .transform_values { |a| a.flat_map(&:last) }
```

See [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) (introduced in Ruby v2.5) and [Enumerable#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map).

Note that

```
str.each_char
   .with_index
   .group_by(&:first)
  #=> {"h"=>[["h", 0]], "e"=>[["e", 1]], "l"=>[["l", 2], ["l", 3]],
  #    "o"=>[["o", 4]]}
```

Answer (score 8):

It can be done, but will confuse other Ruby programmers.A normal hash treats a key "a" as identical to another "a". Unless a little known feature `.compare_by_identity` is used:

```
h = {}.compare_by_identity
"hello".chars.each_with_index{|c,i| h[c] = i}
p h    # => {"h"=>0, "e"=>1, "l"=>2, "l"=>3, "o"=>4}
```

Comment: "but will confuse other Ruby programmers." which is a good reason to not use it unless there are big warning signs posted all around it.

Comment: `h["l"] # => nil` :-/

Answer (score 3):

Another option you can use is zipping two enumerations together.

```
s = "hello"
s.chars.zip(0..s.size)
```

This yields: `[["h", 0], ["e", 1], ["l", 2], ["l", 3], ["o", 4]]`

Comment: or `s.each_char.with_index.to_a`

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Ruby and I am sure this can be refactored, but another alternative might be:

```
arr1 = "Hello".split(%r{\s*})

arr2 = []

for i in 0..arr1.size - 1
  arr2 << i
end

o = arr1.zip(arr2)

a_h = []

o.each do |i|
  a_h << Hash[*i]
end

p a_h.each_with_object({}) { |k, v| k.each { |kk,vv| (v[kk] ||= []) << vv } }
```

> => {"H"=>[0], "e"=>[1], "l"=>[2, 3], "o"=>[4]}